# R; separate columns with comma into rows

Tags: r, rows

I'm having trouble to split column into multiple rows even after using `separate_rows` function.
It gives me the following error..

> Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.

INPUT:

```
ID      Colours         Shapes
1       Red             Triangle  
1       Red             Square  
2       Green, Black    Circle
2       Green, Black    Triangle  
3       Blue            Square  
3       Blue            Oval
```

OUTPUT:

```
ID      Colours         Shapes
1       Red             Triangle  
1       Red             Square  
2       Green           Circle
2       Green           Triangle
2       Black           Circle
2       Black           Triangle  
3       Blue            Square  
3       Blue            Oval
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried to use `separate_rows` with your data and I had no problems:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
                 Colours = c("Red", "Red", "Green, Black", "Green, Black", "Blue", "Blue"),
                 Shapes = c("Triangle", "Square", "Circle", "Triangle", "Square", "Oval"))

library(tidyr)
df %>% separate_rows(Colours, sep = ", ")
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#>      ID Colours Shapes  
#>   <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   
#> 1     1 Red     Triangle
#> 2     1 Red     Square  
#> 3     2 Green   Circle  
#> 4     2 Black   Circle  
#> 5     2 Green   Triangle
#> 6     2 Black   Triangle
#> 7     3 Blue    Square  
#> 8     3 Blue    Oval
```

Comment: `tidyr::separate_rows(df, Colours)` or even `tidytext::unnest_tokens(df, Colours, Colours)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can use `tidyverse` functions to separate rows by comma. The solution will work for n elements separated by comma. Initially, reshape data to long with `pivot_longer()`, then separate rows with `separate_rows()`. As ids for rows were necessary you can reshape to wide to obtain the expected output. Finally, use `fill()` to complete the missing values and `arrange()` to give the desired order. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
newdf <- df %>% mutate(id=row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(ID,id)) %>%
  separate_rows(value,sep=',') %>%
  mutate(value=trimws(value)) %>%
  group_by(id,name) %>% mutate(id2=row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from=value) %>%
  fill(Shapes) %>% ungroup() %>% select(-c(id,id2)) %>%
  arrange(ID,Colours)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
     ID Colours Shapes  
  <int> <chr>   <chr>   
1     1 Red     Triangle
2     1 Red     Square  
3     2 Black   Circle  
4     2 Black   Triangle
5     2 Green   Circle  
6     2 Green   Triangle
7     3 Blue    Square  
8     3 Blue    Oval
```